# Add between clause in a LINQ expression with OR operator

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a table where I have records of reservations. I need to extract all the bookings which falls under a month. Therefore, Considering both the startdate and enddate of the bookings. I have tried the below code but not getting exact results.

`var c = data.Where(x => x.stDate>= startDate && x.stDate<= endDate || x.enDate>= startDate && x.enDate<= endDate).ToList();`

//startDate = start of a month
//enddate= end of that month
Am I missing something? Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about a booking that starts in this month and ends in the other month? I want to know if I got your code right. because it seems to me that there should be no `||` and all should be `&&`

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani yes, I have to consider that record too. What ever entry is there in the table for a particular month.

Comment: you are missing some parenthesis.. other than that, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your comment that you also need those records that start in the previous month and ends in this month + those that start in this month but ends in the other month so enclosing ands in parentheses would do the trick.

```
var c = data.Where(x => (x.stDate>= startDate && x.stDate<= endDate) ||
(x.enDate>= startDate && x.enDate<= endDate) ||
(x.stDate < startDate && x.enDate > endDate))).ToList();
```

and you should also consider those that start before this month and ends after this month (pretty unlikely but logically possilbe):

```
x.stDate < startDate && x.enDate > endDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `x.enDate>=x.stDate`, which is a good constraint to be enforced on the database level to ensure sanity of the data, all you need is

```
var c = data.Where(x => x.stDate <= endDate && x.enDate >= startDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to seperate && and || operands.
And also if you are checking a dateRange always must use just date and exclude time.

```
var c = data.Where(x => (x.stDate.Date >= startDate.Date && x.stDate.Date <= endDate.Date ) || (x.enDate.Date >= startDate.Date && x.enDate.Date <= endDate.Date ).ToList();
```

Comment: && has higher priority than ||, so parentheses are not necessary.